# PHP Conditional Statement Not Working

Tags: php, parsing, printing, conditional-statements

I have 2 different JSON files and want to print a message if 2 nodes have the same revision number. However, when the revision is the same for 2 nodes, my code does not go through the conditional. I even included print statements to verify that both revision numbers are the same. Here is my code:

```
foreach($xml_2->logentry as $node2):
            $revision_log = $node2[0]['revision'];
            print "revision: ";
            print $revision;
            echo "<br>";
            print "revision_log: ";
            print $revision_log;
            echo "<br>";

            if ($revision_log == $revision){
                print "Got inside of if statement";
                $msg = $node2->msg;
                print "msg: ";
                print $msg;
                echo "<br>";
            }
        endforeach;
```

Here is some of the output:

```
revision_log: 5066
revision: 1282
revision_log: 3757
revision: 1282
revision_log: 3756
revision: 1282
revision_log: 1285
revision: 1282
revision_log: 1282
revision: 1282
revision_log: 1247
revision: 1282
revision_log: 1140
```

Now, at revision 1282, the code should jump into my conditional, but it does not. Does anyone know why? "Got inside of if statement" is never printed.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php no way to know where `$revision` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that the $revision variable was a string. I declared it the same way as $revision_log. The JSON must have been different. I just converted $revision to an int variable and everything is working now.

```
foreach($xml_2->logentry as $node2):
            $revision_log = $node2[0]['revision'];                                                      
            $revision_int = (int) $revision;
            if ($revision_log == $revision_int){
                $msg = $node2->msg;
                print "Commit Message: ";
                print $msg;
                echo "<br>";
            }
endforeach;
```